# how to get focus to the next editable column in gridview using jquery

Tags: jquery

I am using VS 2005, ASP.NET,C#.NET AND JQUERY.
I have gridview in update panel.
I have tab index of one cell $(this).attr('tabIndex')
I have to move the focus to the next editable cell .
how to find the tab index of the next cell and give focus to it when pressing arrow keys

thanks in advance
george n t

```
        <%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="frmPLEntryMonthWise.aspx.cs" Inherits="frmPLEntryMonthWise" %>
        <%@ Register Assembly="System.Web.Extensions, Version=1.0.61025.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"
            Namespace="System.Web.UI" TagPrefix="asp" %>

        <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

        <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
        <head id="Head1" runat="server">
            <title>P & L Entry - All Account (Cumulative)</title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
               <style type="text/css">
                .GVFixedHeader { font-weight:bold;  border-width:1px 1px;border:solid #d3d3d3; position:relative; top:expression(this.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.scrollTop-1);}
            </style>
            <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
                function getScrollBottom(p_oElem)
                {
                    return p_oElem.scrollHeight - p_oElem.scrollTop - p_oElem.clientHeight;
                }
            </script>
        <link href="includes/text.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <link href="style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />

        <script type="text/javascript" src="includes/jquery.js">function DIV1_onclick() {}

        </script>

        <style type="text/css"> 
        .container {
            width:900px;
            height:1000px;
            overflow:hidden;
            padding:20px;
        }
        </style>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="includes/plBooking.js"> function isNumberKey() {}</script> 
        <script type="text/javascript" src="includes/plBooking.js">function checkBlankPressTab() {}</script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="includes/plBooking.js">function checkBlankPressOnblur() {}</script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="includes/plBooking.js"> function checkValidNo(){}</script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="includes/plBooking.js"> function fnSum(){}</script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="includes/plBooking.js">function fnRound(){}</script> 
        <script type="text/javascript" src="includes/plBooking.js"> function isNumberKey1(){}</script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="includes/plBooking.js"> function isNumberKey2(){}</script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="includes/plBooking.js">function appendZero(){   }</script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="includes/plBooking.js"> function validate_Save(){}</script>
         <script src="JQuery/jquery-1.4.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

            <script src="JQuery/jquery.keynavigation.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

           <%-- <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
                $(document).ready(function() {
                    //For navigating using left and right arrow of the keyboard
                    var gridview = $("#grdView");
                    $.keynavigation(gridview);
                });
            </script>--%>
             <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
            $("body").keydown(function(e) {
            alert('hi');
          if(e.keyCode == 40) { // down
               $(':focus').nextAll(':has(["tabIndex"]):not([tabIndex=-1])').focus();
          }
           else if(e.keyCode == 38) { // up
               $(':focus').prevAll(':has(["tabIndex"]):not([tabIndex=-1])').focus();            
         }
           else if(e.keyCode == 37) { // left
               $(':focus').prevAll(':has(["tabIndex"]):not([tabIndex=-1])').focus();            
         }
           else if(e.keyCode == 39) { // right
               $(':focus').prevAll(':has(["tabIndex"]):not([tabIndex=-1])').focus();            
         }
         });
         </script>
        <%--<script type="text/javascript" src="includes/plBooking.js"> function fnShowTotal(){}</script>--%>

        <%--<link href="cal/popcalendar.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />--%>
        </head>
        <body id="body" runat="server" onkeydown="">

        <form id="Form1" runat="server" >

        <div class="container" id="DIV1" onclick="return DIV1_onclick()" style="width: 1219px; height: 540px;" >
            <asp:ScriptManager id="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
              <Scripts>
                    <asp:ScriptReference Path="~/FixFocus.js" />
                </Scripts>
            </asp:ScriptManager>      
              <div >    
              <asp:Label ID="lblDetails" runat="server" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="Black" Text="Company Name" Width="1080px"></asp:Label>      
               <asp:Label ID="lblExRate" runat="server" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="Black" Text="Exchange Rate"  ></asp:Label> 
            <table style="height: 325px; width: 98%;"  > 

                    <tr>
                        <td align="left" colspan="4" valign="top" style="width: 682px; height: 243px;"><strong></strong>

                             <div style="height:340px; width:1198px; overflow-y:scroll; overflow: auto;">
                                 <asp:UpdatePanel id="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" ><contenttemplate>
                           <asp:GridView  ID="grdView" runat="server" Width="900px" AutoGenerateColumns="False"  ShowFooter="True" CssClass="grid" DataKeyNames="accCode" style="overflow: scroll" OnRowDataBound="grdView_RowDataBound"    >
                                     <HeaderStyle CssClass="GVFixedHeader" />
                                     <FooterStyle CssClass="GVFixedFooter" />                                   
                                <Columns>
                                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Acc.No." >                                
                                        <ItemStyle Width="70px" />
                                        <ItemTemplate>
                                            <asp:Label ID="lblAccCode" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("accUserCode") %>'></asp:Label>
                                        </ItemTemplate>
                                        <FooterTemplate>
                                        </FooterTemplate>

                                        <ControlStyle Width="70px" />
                                    </asp:TemplateField>
                                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="P &amp; L Account Name">                                
                                        <ItemStyle Width="190px" />
                                        <ItemTemplate>
                                            <asp:Label ID="lblAccName" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("accName") %>'></asp:Label>
                                        </ItemTemplate>
                                        <FooterTemplate>
                                         <asp:TextBox ID="txtTotal" Width="190px" runat="server" Font-Bold="true" Font-Size="Medium" style="text-align:right;" ReadOnly="true" BorderStyle="none" BorderColor="honeydew" BackColor="honeyDew" Text="Total" ></asp:TextBox>
                                        </FooterTemplate>
                                         <ControlStyle Width="190px" />
                                    </asp:TemplateField>

                                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="D">                                
                                        <ItemStyle Width="10px" />
                                        <ItemTemplate>
                                            <asp:Label ID="lblDeprec" runat="server" ></asp:Label>
                                        </ItemTemplate>
                                        <FooterTemplate>
                                        </FooterTemplate>
                                         <ControlStyle Width="10px" />
                                    </asp:TemplateField>
                                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="B">                                
                                        <ItemStyle Width="10px" />
                                        <ItemTemplate>
                                            <asp:Label ID="lblProv" runat="server" ></asp:Label>
                                        </ItemTemplate>
                                        <FooterTemplate>
                                        </FooterTemplate>
                                         <ControlStyle Width="10px" />
                                    </asp:TemplateField>
                                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="C">                                
                                        <ItemStyle Width="10px" />
                                        <ItemTemplate>
                                            <asp:Label ID="lblCons" runat="server" ></asp:Label>
                                        </ItemTemplate>
                                        <FooterTemplate>
                                        </FooterTemplate>
                                         <ControlStyle Width="10px" />
                                    </asp:TemplateField>

                                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="M-1 Cumul." >  
                                     <HeaderTemplate>
                                        <asp:Label Width="60px" ID="lblHCumul" runat="server" Text="<%# fillHeaderCumul() %> "  ></asp:Label>
                                    </HeaderTemplate>                                                          
                                        <ItemStyle Width="60px" />
                                        <ItemTemplate>
                                            <asp:TextBox Width="60px" ID="lblPCum" ReadOnly="true" BorderStyle="none" BorderColor="honeydew" BackColor="honeyDew"  runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("PCum") %>' TabIndex="-1"  ></asp:TextBox>
                                        </ItemTemplate>
                                        <FooterTemplate>
                                        <asp:TextBox ID="lblFPCum" Width="60px"  style="text-align:right;" Font-Bold="true" ReadOnly="true"  BorderStyle="none"  BorderColor="honeydew" BackColor="honeyDew"  runat="server" /> 
                                        </FooterTemplate>    
                                        <ControlStyle Width="60px" />
                                    </asp:TemplateField>

                                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Budget"> 
                                    <HeaderTemplate>
                                    <asp:Label Width="60px" ID="lblHBudget" runat="server" Text='<%# fillHeaderBudget() %>'></asp:Label>
                                    </HeaderTemplate>                               
                                        <ItemStyle Width="60px" />
                                        <ItemTemplate>
                                            <asp:TextBox Width="60px" ID="lblMBudget" ReadOnly="true" BorderStyle="none" BorderColor="honeydew" BackColor="honeyDew" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("MBudget") %>' TabIndex="-1"></asp:TextBox>
                                        </ItemTemplate>
                                        <FooterTemplate>
                                        <asp:TextBox ID="lblFMBudget" Width="60px" style="text-align:right;" Font-Bold="true" ReadOnly="true" BorderStyle="none" BorderColor="honeydew" BackColor="honeyDew" runat="server" /> 
                                        </FooterTemplate>
                                        <ControlStyle Width="60px" />
                                    </asp:TemplateField>

                                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="P &amp; L As Per Book">
                                     <ItemStyle Width="80px" BackColor="White"/>
                                    <ItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:TextBox Width="80px" ID="txtPL" runat="server" text='<%# Eval("PL") %>'    BorderStyle="None" BorderColor="white"    >
                                    </asp:TextBox>
                                   </ItemTemplate>
                                   <FooterTemplate>
                                     <%--<asp:TextBox ID="lblFPL" runat="server" />--%> 
                                        <asp:TextBox ID="lblFPL" Width="80px" style="text-align:right;" Font-Bold="true" ReadOnly="true" BorderStyle="none" BorderColor="honeydew" BackColor="honeyDew" runat="server"   /> 
                                    </FooterTemplate>
                                    <ControlStyle Width="80px" />
                                    </asp:TemplateField>

                                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Adjustments">
                                     <ItemStyle Width="80px" BackColor="White"/>
                                    <ItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:TextBox Width="80px" ID="txtCorrection" runat="server" text='<%# Eval("Correction") %>'   BorderStyle="None" BorderColor="white"   >
                                    </asp:TextBox>
                                   </ItemTemplate>   
                                    <FooterTemplate>
                                        <asp:TextBox ID="lblFCorrection" Width="80px" style="text-align:right;" Font-Bold="true" ReadOnly="true" BorderStyle="none" BorderColor="honeydew" BackColor="honeyDew" runat="server" /> 
                                        </FooterTemplate> 
                                   <ControlStyle Width="80px" />                        
                                   </asp:TemplateField>

                                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Cumul."> 
                                    <HeaderTemplate>
                                        <asp:Label Width="60px" ID="lblHMCumul" runat="server" Text="<%# fillHeaderMonthCumul() %> "></asp:Label>
                                    </HeaderTemplate>                              
                                        <ItemStyle Width="60px" />
                                        <ItemTemplate>
                                            <asp:TextBox Width="60px" ID="lblMCum"  BorderStyle="none" BorderColor="honeydew" BackColor="honeyDew" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("MCum") %>' TabIndex="-1"></asp:TextBox>
                                        </ItemTemplate>
                                         <FooterTemplate>
                                        <asp:TextBox ID="lblFMCum"  Width="60px" style="text-align:right;" Font-Bold="true" ReadOnly="true" BorderStyle="none" BorderColor="honeydew" BackColor="honeyDew" runat="server"  /> 
                                        </FooterTemplate>
                                        <ControlStyle Width="60px" />
                                    </asp:TemplateField>

                                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Month Actual">                               
                                        <ItemStyle Width="60px" />
                                        <ItemTemplate>
                                            <asp:TextBox Width="60px" ID="lblDiffAmt"  BorderStyle="none" BorderColor="honeydew" BackColor="honeyDew" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("DAmt") %>' TabIndex="-1"></asp:TextBox>
                                        </ItemTemplate>
                                         <FooterTemplate>
                                        <asp:TextBox ID="lblFDAmt" Width="60px" style="text-align:right;" Font-Bold="true" ReadOnly="true" BorderStyle="none" BorderColor="honeydew" BackColor="honeyDew" runat="server" /> 
                                        </FooterTemplate>
                                        <ControlStyle Width="60px" />


                                    </asp:TemplateField>

                                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Var. In %">                                
                                        <ItemStyle Width="60px" />
                                        <ItemTemplate>
                                            <asp:TextBox Width="60px" ID="lblDiffPcnt"  BorderStyle="none" BorderColor="honeydew" BackColor="honeyDew" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("DPcnt") %>' TabIndex="-1"></asp:TextBox>
                                        </ItemTemplate>
                                    </asp:TemplateField>    

                                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Remarks" >                           
                                     <ItemStyle Width="195px" BackColor="White" />
                                    <ItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:TextBox Width="195px" ID="txtComment" runat="server" text='<%# Eval("Comment") %>' BorderStyle="None" BorderColor="white" >
                                    </asp:TextBox>
                                    <asp:HiddenField ID="HFaccCode" runat="server" Value='<%# Eval("accCode") %>' />
                                    <asp:HiddenField ID="HFprovision" runat="server" Value='<%# Eval("provision") %>' />
                                     <asp:HiddenField ID="HFdepreciation" runat="server" Value='<%# Eval("depreciation") %>' />
                                    <asp:HiddenField ID="HFconsolidation" runat="server" Value='<%# Eval("consolidation") %>' />
                                    <asp:HiddenField ID="HFaccType" runat="server" Value='<%# Eval("accAccType") %>' />
                                     <asp:HiddenField ID="HFplentryCurrentMonthstatus" runat="server" Value='<%# Eval("plentryCurrentMonthstatus") %>' />

                                   </ItemTemplate>
                                    <ControlStyle Width="195px" />
                                   </asp:TemplateField>

                                    <asp:BoundField DataField="provision" HeaderText="provision" Visible="False" />
                                    <asp:BoundField DataField="accCode" HeaderText="provision" Visible="False"  />
                                </Columns>



                            </asp:GridView></contenttemplate>
                                 </asp:UpdatePanel>
                               </div>                      

                    </td>                        
                    </tr>               
                   </table>        
                    </div>

                <tr>
                    <td colspan="2" style="height: 15px"> &nbsp;&nbsp
                     <strong><asp:Label ID="lblName" runat="server" Text="Version : "></asp:Label></strong>
                         <asp:TextBox ID="txtVersion" runat="server" CssClass="txt" Width="100px" ReadOnly="true"></asp:TextBox>
                      </td>
                        <td align="center" style="width: 100px; height: 15px">&nbsp;&nbsp;              
                        </td>
                </tr>
            <table >
                <tr>

                    <td colspan="2" style="height: 27px">
                    <asp:HyperLink ID="hlBack" runat="server" NavigateUrl="~/frmPL.aspx" Font-Underline="True">Back</asp:HyperLink>
                    &nbsp;<strong><asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" Text="D -"  ></asp:Label></strong>           
                        <asp:Label ID="Label4" runat="server" ForeColor="blue" Text="Cash Flow Account" Width="130px" style="left: 8px; position: relative; top: 0px"></asp:Label>
                    &nbsp;<strong><asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="B -" ></asp:Label></strong>           
                        <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" ForeColor="blue" Text="Budget Account" Width="120px" style="left: 8px; position: relative; top: 0px"></asp:Label>
                       &nbsp;<strong><asp:Label ID="Label7" runat="server" Text="C -"   ></asp:Label></strong>           
                        <asp:Label ID="Label8" runat="server" ForeColor="Blue" Text="Consolidation Account" Width="132px" style="left: 8px; position: relative; top: 0px"></asp:Label>
                        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                         <strong> <asp:Label ID="Label20" runat="server"  Text="Var. in % - "></asp:Label></strong>
                  <asp:Label ID="Label6" runat="server" ForeColor="blue" Text="Difference between Month Actual and Cumul Previous Months" ></asp:Label>
                        <%--<strong><asp:Label ID="Label5" runat="server" Text="Var.  -" ></asp:Label></strong>           
                        <asp:Label ID="Label6" runat="server" ForeColor="blue" Text="Difference between current month and previous month" ></asp:Label>--%>
                        <asp:Label ID="lblError" runat="server" ForeColor="Red" Text="Error" Width="224px" style="left: 8px; position: relative; top: 0px"></asp:Label>
                      </td>
                       <td align="center" style="width: 100px; height: 46px">
                           &nbsp;</td>
                        <td align="center">
                            &nbsp;
                        <asp:Button ID="btnShow" runat="server" CssClass="button"  Text="Show Total" Width="100px" OnClick="btnShow_Click" /></td>
                          <td align="center" style="width: 100px; height: 27px">
                        <asp:Button ID="btnSave" runat="server" CssClass="button" OnClick="btnSave_Click"
                            Text="Save" Width="100px"  /><%-- <asp:Button ID="btnExit" runat="server" CssClass="button" OnClick="btnExit_Click"
                            Text="Exit" Width="100px" />&nbsp;--%></td>
                </tr>

            </table>
            </div>  
          </form>
        </body>
        </html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To capture Up/Down + switch to next/previous cell with attr tabIndex:

```
$("body").keydown(function(e) {
  if(e.keyCode == 40) { // down
       $(':focus').nextAll(':has(["tabIndex"]').focus();
  }
   else if(e.keyCode == 38) { // up
       $(':focus').prevAll(':has(["tabIndex"]').focus();            
 }
 });
```

**UPDATE:** 
updating selector to ignore -1 tabindex

```
$("body").keydown(function(e) {
  if(e.keyCode == 40) { // down
       $(':focus').nextAll(':has(["tabIndex"]):not([tabIndex=-1])').focus();
  }
   else if(e.keyCode == 38) { // up
       $(':focus').prevAll(':has(["tabIndex"]):not([tabIndex=-1])').focus();            
 }
 });
```

**UPDATE:**
Please see this fiddle: 
    http://jsfiddle.net/6a6e6/

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$("body").keydown(function (e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 40) { // down
        $(':focus').nextAll('input:not([tabIndex=-1]):first').focus()
    } else if (e.keyCode == 39) { //right
        $(':focus').nextAll('input:not([tabIndex=-1]):first').focus()
    } else if (e.keyCode == 38) { //up
        $(':focus').prevAll('input:not([tabIndex=-1]):first').focus()
    } else if (e.keyCode == 37) { //left
        $(':focus').prevAll('input:not([tabIndex=-1]):first').focus()
    }
});
});
```

**Update:**

To make this work with the GridView you have - you must add the TabIndex to the actual asp:textboxes witin your grids template definition -  TabIndex="1" /etc..
for example:

```
<ItemTemplate>
 <asp:TextBox Width="80px" ID="txtCorrection" runat="server" text="whatever"   BorderStyle="None" BorderColor="white"  TabIndex="1"   >
 </asp:TextBox>
</ItemTemplate>
```

I tried it in an asp application and it changes the case to lowercase, so you must update the keydown function to contain:

```
    if (e.keyCode == 40) { // down
    $(':focus').nextAll('input:not([tabindex=-1]):first').focus()
} else if (e.keyCode == 39) { //right
    $(':focus').nextAll('input:not([tabindex=-1]):first').focus()
} else if (e.keyCode == 38) { //up
    $(':focus').prevAll('input:not([tabindex=-1]):first').focus()
} else if (e.keyCode == 37) { //left
    $(':focus').prevAll('input:not([tabindex=-1]):first').focus()
}
```

Comment: Hi , all readonly columns have tabindex -1. I got the present cell tabindex from $(this).attr('tabIndex').   Now i want the tabindex of next cell in the same row. if it is -1 , no need of focus.The focus should go to the next cell with tabindex not equal to -1

Comment: Where should i call this function, in gridview keydown or body keydown

Comment: put <script type="text/javascript"> the updated code </script> on your page's html.

Comment: Its not working .The following is my webpage design.

Comment: Thanks that was a big help  - @user3253876 please see the fiddle - It should work the way you want.. if you wish to have up/down working in a grid format I can probally do that also, but for now, left/up do the same, and right down do the same.. You can have if with OR's in there but left it in there as you had it for clarity.

Comment: I have seen the fiddle.it was nice work in textboxes. This should work in our gridview in update panel

Comment: OK - does this answer your question? can you mark as answer if it is answer, thanks :) @user3253876

Comment: Hi JF, Its not working in my gridview.Can you help me

Comment: @user3253876 can't do it in a fiddle as its messing up because of what ASP does to the gridviews elements at runtime.., so see updated answer..

Comment: Which version of Jquery is required for it?

Comment: I tested with version 2 and it works.. id say realistically all versions shud b able to run this.